# Iterate over multimap<int, weak_ptr<>>

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap, weak-ptr

I am trying to iterate over a `multimap<int, weak_ptr<RenderObject>>` but for some reason using the for loop below causes an error.

```
using RenderIndex = int32_t;
class RenderObject
{
public:
   RenderIndex m_render_index;
   // rest of class definition
};

std::multimap<RenderIndex, std::weak_ptr<RenderObject>> m_render_objects;
for (auto renderPair : m_render_objects) // error occurs here
{
    // call render function..
}
```

The error visual studio complains about is `l-value specifies const object`. After looking through the error output in vs I think the problem is from the `weak_ptr<>` as if I try the same thing but with a `shared_ptr` as the value in the map there are no errors.

My question is if my hypothesis is correct that the `weak_ptr<>` is causing the error what is the reason/explanation for this behaviour?

I could always use a list of weak_ptr as this does not seem to have the same issue but I want to have the `RenderObject` sorted based on render order and a map gives this by default whereas a list would require a resort on each insertion/change/removal which would be very inefficient.

Console Output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Engine, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>RenderLayer.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\utility(246): error C2166: l-value specifies const object
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\utility(245): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::operator =(std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &&) noexcept(false)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=otw::RenderIndex,
1>            _Ty=std::weak_ptr<otw::RenderObject>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\algorithm(1325): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::operator =(std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &&) noexcept(false)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=otw::RenderIndex,
1>            _Ty=std::weak_ptr<otw::RenderObject>
1>        ]
1>c:\outlaw\outlaw_games_engine\engine\renderlayer.cpp(13): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=otw::RenderIndex,
1>            _Ty=std::weak_ptr<otw::RenderObject>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\xstring(2007): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<_Elem,_Alloc>>::_String_alloc<const _Alloc&,void>(_Any_alloc)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=wchar_t,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>,
1>            _Any_alloc=const std::allocator<wchar_t> &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\xstring(2006): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<_Elem,_Alloc>>::_String_alloc<const _Alloc&,void>(_Any_alloc)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=wchar_t,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>,
1>            _Any_alloc=const std::allocator<wchar_t> &
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\string(516): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>::basic_string<_Elem*,void>(_Iter,_Iter,const _Alloc &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=wchar_t,
1>            _Iter=wchar_t *,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\string(516): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>::basic_string<_Elem*,void>(_Iter,_Iter,const _Alloc &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=wchar_t,
1>            _Iter=wchar_t *,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<wchar_t>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\string(596): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>> std::_Integral_to_string<wchar_t,int>(const _Ty)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>Done building project "Engine.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

***EDIT***

I have tried `for(const auto& renderPair : m_render_objects)` and `for(auto& renderPair : m_render_objects)`. Also for and while loop variations using the iterator. All of which produce the exact same error.

***NOTE***

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with C++17.

Comment: Try `for (auto& renderPair : m_render_objects)`

Comment: @user9212993 I have actually already tried that. I produces the exact same error. I have updated my question to include my previous attempts to resolve the error

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your exact error please!

Comment: @user9212993 I do not see how this is not a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. It provides the error output, the code that causes the problem and the required class definitions. I could add a tone more information but then that would not be minimal. Please give more information as to what you need to help.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the error from the code you posted: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d43df04220ca1e1

Comment: I added in every relevant class definition removing getter setters and other methods that are irrelevant. this should help

Comment: Can you show what is in line 13 on file: c:\outlaw\outlaw_games_engine\engine\renderlayer.cpp?

Comment: @Amadeus line 13 is the `for (auto renderPair : m_render_objects) // error occurs here`

Comment: As said above, please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Such an example is one that I can simply copy-paste it on my machine and compile it. Currently your snippets don't fulfill this. I need to put them together and in the process try to figure what headers do I need to include(e.g. what is STRCODE and where is it declared). If you have dependencies on non-standard headers, change your class to something dummy in order to remove dependencies, this may actually may help you find the error. I hope now you see why your code is not minimal, complete and verifiable.

Comment: Looks more like a problem with your map key class RenderIndex. There is some problem with a std::string copy/assignment. Try to double-clich the notes in the error message to see rhe context

Comment: @A.A RenderIndex is just a type alias for `std::size_t`.

Comment: @user9212993 I updated the question so that it has definitions for STRCODE and RenderIndex

Comment: @Matthew What's so hard to get about [MCVE] actually?

Comment: @user9212993 If this edit still is not enough then I am truly lost.

Comment: @Matthew Why don't you simply following the instructions from that link I provided multiple times for you now? Doing so might already be helpful to solve that problem yourself. What you added is useless in regard of what I've been asking for.

Comment: @Matthew an [mcve] is a code that I can paste on my machine, compile it and found the same issue you are having. The code you provide does not allow this

Comment: @Amadeus I understand what you mean now. Thank you for the input. I just figured out what the problem was. I did not realize that you can't use `std::remove_if` on a map and for whatever reason, it errors on the loop above and not on the remove_if. That would be why you couldn't reproduce it on your machine. for the future, I will test my code snippet on something such as compiler explorer and ensure it is receiving the same error. thank you for the help